# Property of $T^2=I_V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T:V\to V$ a linear transformation such that $T^2 = T\circ T = I_V$. Define:

$V_1=\{v\in V\mid T(v)=v\}$ and $V_2=\{v\in V\mid T(v)=-v\}$

Prove that $V=V_1\oplus V_2$.

Disjoint union is easy to show. However, how can I show every $v$ = $v_1 + (v-v_1)$, $v-v_1$ is in $V_2$, where $v_1\in V_1$?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but it's proving difficult to find "the original".

Comment: There it is. ${}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your decomposition exists, look at the consequences, and realize it leads to showing existence.

You already have a good start writing $v=v_1+(v-v_1)$, with $Tv_1=v_1$ and $T(v-v_1)=-(v-v_1)$.  Well if that's true, then $Tv=2v_1-v$, so you can see that $v_1=\dfrac{Tv+v}{2}$.  Now, without assuming a priori that this works, show that it does.

Comment: Interesting way to break it down!

Comment: Thanks.  Is similar to how I think of decomposing a function on $\mathbb R$ into even and odd parts: Suppose it's true, plug in $-x$, and the consquences lead to the formulas for them, which then are easily verified to always work.  Actually it is pretty much the same because "plugging in $-x$" is a square root of the identity, the even and odd parts being eigenvectors for eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
v = \frac{v + Tv}{2} + \frac{v - Tv}{2}
$$